# How can i equal random function and input value?

Tags: function, if-statement, canvas, equals

My [**Demo Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EQmU2/2/)

My Code

**Html**

```
<canvas id="random" title="Click to Change"></canvas>
<input name="rand" type="text" id="rand" data-filter="false"/>
<span id="rands"></span>
```

**Jquery**

```
function Random() {
        var length = 6,
            charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
            retVal = "";
        for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
            retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
        }
        return retVal;
    }
    var ctx = document.getElementById("random").getContext('2d');
    ctx.font = "50px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(Random(), 0, 40);


$("#random").click(function () {
    if($("#rand").val() !== Random()){
    ctx.clearRect ( 0,0,1000,1000 );
    ctx.fillText(Random(), 0, 40);
    }
});



$('#rand').bind('keypress keyup change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== Random()) {
            $(this).addClass('false').removeClass('true').attr('data-filter', 'false'), $("#" + this.id + "s").css({
                "color": "#C41111"
            }).text("Characters in conflict with each other!");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('true').removeClass('false').attr('data-filter', 'true'), $("#" + this.id + "s").css({
                "color": "#7FAC25"
            }).text($(this).val() + " is accepted!");
        }
    });
```

I want equal this `if($("#rand").val() !== Random())` but i can't ?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make a call to Random(), a new value is generated. So, when you are comparing here `if ($(this).val() !== Random())`

It is comparing against a new value. That is why they will almost never be equal!

```
var Deli = {
    randomDeger:false,
    random:function() {
        var length = 6,
            charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
            retVal = "";
        for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
            retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
        }
        this.randomDeger = retVal;
        return retVal;
    }
}

    var ctx = document.getElementById("random").getContext('2d');
    ctx.font = "50px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(Deli.random(), 0, 40);


$("#random").click(function () {
    if($("#rand").val() !== Deli.randomDeger){
    ctx.clearRect ( 0,0,1000,1000 );
    ctx.fillText(Deli.random(), 0, 40);
    }
});



$('#rand').bind('keypress keyup change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== Deli.randomDeger) {
            $(this).addClass('false').removeClass('true').attr('data-filter', 'false'), $("#" + this.id + "s").css({
                "color": "#C41111"
            }).text("Characters in conflict with each other!");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('true').removeClass('false').attr('data-filter', 'true'), $("#" + this.id + "s").css({
                "color": "#7FAC25"
            }).text($(this).val() + " is accepted!");
        }
    });
```